# System.Data.SQLite type affinity int in string column

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, system.data.sqlite

From what I've read about SQLite it has a feature called Type Affinity which means that data types are not strictly enforced ([More info here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).

I am reading from a database created in another application using POCO objects with EF4.1, **the problem arises when a supposedly string field has an integer in it**. I could understand an exception being thrown if an int field had a non-numeric string in it... but why would this screw up my app?

This is a sample of my test code, I've removed everything else until I was left with the bare minimum of code that makes this pop up.

```
Public Class TVSerie
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property PrettyName As String
End Class

Public Class TVSeriesDb
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property TVSeries As DbSet(Of TVSerie)
End Class

Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim db As New TVSeriesDb
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim series = db.TVSeries.Where(Function(c) c.PrettyName.Length > 0)
        For Each s In series
            sb.Append(s.Id & "-" & s.PrettyName & "<br/>")
        Next
        Return Content(sb.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

The error is popping up in the "PrettyName" column with the TVSeries 24:

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ) +492
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetString(Int32 i) +131
[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target,   Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +251
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +342
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +79
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +167
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +218
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +291
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +170
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +84
   Test.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Projects\PlayListShuffler\Test\Controllers\HomeController.vb:14
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8920029
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that sqlite is not strongly typed (which plays very nicely with a dynamically typed language like Python) the strongly typed nature of .NET is enforced in the wrapper. So that the type of the column detected when the table is read is the type that is required by Reader.Getxxx(n).